# How to stop a jQuery floating div from sliding below the footer?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, slide

I'm using the following code to implement a sliding right sidebar that slides down the page as you scroll down and follows the page back up as you scroll up.

```
$(function() {
     var offset = $("#col-right").offset();
     var topPadding = 40;
     $(window).scroll(function() {
         if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
             $("#col-right").stop().animate({
                 marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
             });
         } else {
             $("#col-right").stop().animate({
                 marginTop: 30
             });
         };
     });
 });
```

It';s working nicely at the moment, apart from the fact that it slides beyond the footer. I was wondering if anybody could help me tweak the code above so that the sidebar stops sliding when it gets to the footer?

Also, if there was a way to stop the sidebar from sliding if the window is shorter than the sidebar, that would be great too, as at the moment, if you view the page in a small window, it's impossible to view the bottom of the sliding sidebar, as it follows the window as you scroll.

I hope I've made myself clear here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

---

This is where I found the initial code:

http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/

---

Here's an example of my html structure:

```
<body>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="header">

        </div>

        <ul id="menu">
            <li class="current"><a href="#">Your Calculation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#how-it-works" class="slide">How it Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#reasons-why" class="slide">10 Reasons Why</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about-darwin" class="slide">About Darwin</a></li>
            <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
        </ul>

        <h1><span>Welcome Joe Bloggs.</span></h1>


        <div id="col-left">
            <p>example content</p>
        </div>

        <div id="col-right">
            <div id="help-col">
                <h2>Need Help?</h2>
                <p id="help-text"><img src="images/help-lady.jpg" />We’re here to assist you with your needs...</p>
                <div id="contact-details">
                    <p id="help-tel"><span>Tel:</span> xxxxxxxx</p>
                </div>
                <p>OR fill out this form:</p>

                <form id="help-form">
                    <input type="text" name="first-name" value="First Name" />
                    <input type="text" name="surname" value="Surname" />
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="Email"  />
                    <input type="text" name="telephone" value="Telephone" />
                    <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="28">Leave a message</textarea>

                    <input class="submit-help" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <p id="footer-inner">&copy; All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant html code?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(floater.position().bottom <= footer.height()) {
    return false
} else{
    //your fading
}
```

THIS IS NOT TESTED.. just an idea..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plug-in that does that: [fixedIfNeeded.js on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/sleek-php/source/browse/trunk/Sites/SleekBase/Modules/Base/JS/jQuery.fixedIfNeeded.js)

```
$('#element-that-should-float').fixedIfNeeded('#element-to-stop-before');
```

If you don't want to use it perhaps the code can help.

Example of it in use: http://sleekphp.com/docs/ (notice how it stops before the comments section).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

Just compare the window height and the floating div and just put condition to stop the scrolling. this helped me once.!